# Retrieve data as an array of Objects in Neo4j

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, neo4j

There are many relationships and nodes. We want to retrieve data as an array of objects from Neo4j database.

If we MATCH as :

```
MATCH (user: user {name:"x"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r]->(item)
OPTIONAL MATCH (item)-[s]->(approver)
RETURN user, item, approver
```

We get the result as:

```
[{user:{properties:{name:"x"}}, item:{properties:{name:"abc"}}, approver:{properties:{name:"a"}}},
{user:{properties:{name:"x"}}, item:{properties:{name:"abc"}}, approver:{properties:{name:"b"}]}},
{user:{properties:{name:"x"}}, item:{properties:{name:"xyz"}}, approver:{properties:{name:"c"}}},
{user:{properties:{name:"x"}}, item:{properties:{name:"xyz"}},  approver:{properties:{name:"d"}}}  }]
```

We need to get the result similar to inorder to reduce the complexity while handling huge relationships at the client side:

```
[{user:{properties:{name:"x"}}, item:{properties:{name:"abc"}},  approvers:[{properties:{name:"a"}}, {properties:{name:"b"}}]},    
{user:{properties:{name:"x"}}, item:{properties:{name:"xyz"}}, approvers:[{properties:{name:"c"}}, {properties:{name:"d"}}] }]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to COLLECT the items in a list. Try this:

```
MATCH (user: user {name:"x"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r]->(item)
RETURN user, COLLECT(item)
```

You may want to spend some time going over the Cypher cheat sheet and reviewing the COLLECT() function as well as list operations.

EDIT

Looks like you added a potential approver of an item into your description. In that case it looks like you want to group by user and item and have a collection of approvers for them.

```
MATCH (user: user {name:"x"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r]->(item)
OPTIONAL MATCH (item)-[s]->(approver)
RETURN user, item, COLLECT(approver) AS approvers
```